# WMI query returns multiple ManagementObjects

Tags: c#, .net, console, wmi

I am using .NET console application to gather performance data of the system. For one of the counter i am using query as below:

```
SELECT CurrentConnections, ConnectionAttemptsPersec
      FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService
```

This query return four Management objects for my system. 
Does `Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService` return data per processor core? I have four core processor in my system. If not what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This query return four Management objects for my system.

So you have four web sites configured in IIS?

(Looking at Perf Mon's Web Service object – which I believe is the same counter object – I see three instances: `_Total`, `web-site-1` and `web-site-2` (plus `<All instances>` of course).

Checking the `Name` property as well should help to distinguish them.

Comment: How can i find the instances? I am using "ManagementObjectSearcher" to execute WMI queries. And in my IIS i have more than 4 websites configured.

Comment: @RuchitRami Suggest using tools like PowerShell's `Get-WmiObject` (aliased to `gwmi`) to refine your queries before moving to C# (`System.Management` types) or C++ (and the WMI COM API). It is much easier to iterate through all the possibilities from the command line first. Also for performance counters in .NET code [`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) is almost certainly easier.